# NestJS Repository seems to be injected but is in-fact empty?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm currently working on an API with NestJS and Sequelize, and it seems that there is a problem when injecting the repository.
For context, when the service calls this.repo.findByKey the function is undefined and the program fails, but when inspecting with VSCode's debugger, the proptotype had the function inside of it.

Here is a reproduction of the source :

```
// service.ts
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(
    @Inject('REPOSITORY') private repo: IRepository
  ) {
    super();
  }

  async getByCode(code: string) {
    console.log(this.repo);                       >> [class Repository extends BaseRepository]
    console.log(this.repo.findByKey);             >> undefined

    return res = await this.repo.findByKey(code); >> this.repo.findByKey is not a function
  }
}

// repository.ts
@Injectable()
export class Repository
  extends BaseRepository
  implements IRepository
{
  constructor(
    @Inject('DATABASE_HELPER')
    databseHelper: DatabaseHelper,
    private mapper: CountryMapper,
  ) {
    super(databseHelper);
  }

  async findByKey(code: string) -> Promise<DTO> {
    ... never reached
  }
}
```

I cannot find the origim of this problem, is there a dark magician here to help me?

Per request, here is the module configuration :

```
@Module({})
export class ExampleModule {
  static register(typeClass: Type<IService>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      imports: [
        HelperModule,
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([Entity]),
      ],
      module: ExampleModule,
      providers: [
        ExampleMapper,
        {
          provide: 'REPOSITORY',
          useValue: Repository,
        },
        {
          provide: 'SERVICE',
          useClass: typeClass,
        },
      ],
      controllers: [Controller],
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you set up the `REPOSITORY` provider as a custom provider in a module?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I added the module to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting the class itself. So `this.repo` is a constructor that never has been called.

```
        {
          provide: 'REPOSITORY',
          useValue: Repository,
        },
```

`useValue` is suitable for shared values like config objects, connection strings, etc as the name imply.

If you want to inject class instance you need to configure your provider like this

```
        {
          provide: 'REPOSITORY',
          useClass: Repository, // <-- notice useClass
        },
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life, I was stuck for so long on this one issue.